# Basic adding of angular/material fails with Angular 6

Tags: angular-material-6

I simply do the following:

```
ng new my-proj
cd my-proj
ng add @angular/material
```

I get in response the following error:

Your project is not using the default configuration for build and test. 
   The Angular Material schematics can only be used with the default
   configuration

Seriously??  Anyone else?

Config:

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.1
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.1
@angular/cli                      6.2.1
@angular/material                 6.4.7
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.1
@schematics/angular               0.8.1
@schematics/update                0.8.1
rxjs                              6.2.2  
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.19.0
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11438

Comment: That is for a library.  This is THE most basic use case and it fails